# Obfuscate strings at build time with Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, obfuscation

I have an Android app, built with Gradle, with ProGuard enabled. Unfortunately, ProGuard does not obfuscate strings. I know there are other commercial solutions offering this feature, but I don't want to go with commercial products.

I have created my algorithm of obfuscation/deobfuscation as Java class in the Android app, so I can deobfuscate strings at runtime in the app.

What I want know is to be able to obfuscate certain strings, with the algorithm above, at build time with Gradle.

My idea was to have a JSON file with my strings on clear and to have a custom Gradle task to parse them, obfuscate (how since the class is a Java class???) and add the obfuscated value as BuildConfig fields or XML resources (by appending/replacing them in the generated xml file maybe).

The problem is:

- I cannot use the Java method to obfuscate from Gradle (I can run java code, but not getting results...)
- I don't really like the idea to duplicate the algorithm in Groovy or other languages to be able to use it while building with Gradle.

Do you have any solution?
Do you know how the other commercial products are doing?

**Note:** I know very well the difference between encryption and obfuscation and its limits. The objective is not to protect the app, I just want to slow down any casual curious, keeping things simple.